# Datapicker React - Having a hard time displaying the date

Tags: arrays, reactjs, datepicker

I am trying to render several inputs (name, location, # of plants and 2 dates).
The 2 dates dont want to get displayed for some reasons they stay in an array format... I tried trooble shooting in several ways but nothing does :(
Any idea?

Here is the App part

```js
let InitialOwners = [
  { nameOwner: 'Julie S', locationOwner: "Eixample", plantsOwner: "2" , startDateOwner: [{}] , endDateOwner : [] }
];


function App() {

  const [owners, setOwners] = useState(InitialOwners);


 
  // to get the data from PO form
  function handleOwnerData(ownerData) {
    let newOwners = [...owners, ownerData];
    setOwners(newOwners)
    console.log(`Owner Data: ${ownerData.locationOwner} ${ownerData.nameOwner} ${ownerData.plantsOwner} ${ownerData.startDateOwner} ${ownerData.endDateOwner}`)
    }
```

Here is the list part where the data should be displayed

```js
import React  from "react";

function DashboardUsers(props){
    return ( 
        <div className ="Dashboard">
            <h2> Welcome to the Dashboard</h2>
            <h4> Here are the current owners </h4>
            <ul>
                {
                    props.owners.map((owners,i) => (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <li> Name: {owners.nameOwner}</li>
                            <li> Location: {owners.locationOwner} </li>
                            <li> # of plants: {owners.plantsOwner} </li>
                            <li> Start Date: [owners.startDateOwner] </li> 
                            <li> End Date:[owners.endDateOwner] </li>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DashboardUsers;
```

And here is how it looks like on the browser :D
[browser image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyipn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are mapping over an array with objects each entry in the map, in your case 'owners', represents the current object. In that case `owners.startDateOwner` is an array of objects inside an array of objects. If you want to iterate over it you need to nest another map:

```
{
                    props.owners.map((owners,i) => (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <li> Name: {owners.nameOwner}</li>
                            <li> Location: {owners.locationOwner} </li>
                            <li> # of plants: {owners.plantsOwner} </li>
                            <li> Start Date: {owners.startDateOwner.map((ownerStartDate) => <span>{ownerStartDate}</span>)} </li> 
                            <li> End Date:[owners.endDateOwner] </li>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
```

this will iterate over the dates and print them in a `<span>`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not seem to work it tells me {owners.startDateOwner.map}... is not a function. Is there any more simple way to do this? 
I am using DatePicker on React and it seems to display an object instead of a string, is it easy to maybe transform the object into a string?

<div>
    <label> Beginning date
    <DatePicker 
      name = "startDate"
      selected={startDate}
      selectsStart
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      onChange={(date)=>handleChangeDates(date, "startDate")}
      dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      minDate={new Date()}
    />

Comment: Yes, that is what you need to do. I did not write it, because I do not know the properties of your nested objects